# Is Sombra fully invisible when using her Thermoptic Camo

Tags: overwatch

(This question is mostly FYI for this community of what I gather from Blizcon, also [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bkrVI.jpg) are her skills. Source is an Overwatch Developer on a live stream just now)

Is Sombra fully invisible and not seeable by anyone while using her Termoptic Camo? Or is she partially visible in some situations?

Comment: I'm voting to close this as off-topic. Sombra hasn't even released yet. She's only just barely been officially announced.

Comment: Note: Sombra is currently available at a gameplay event at Blizzcon, which imo technically counts as released enough for our purposes

Comment: [According to this meta this is perfectly fine](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/5539/when-is-a-game-publicly-available/5541#5541). The main reason we don't allow questions about unreleased content is because answers will be just speculation, but considering the OPs source is Blizzard then it's not speculation.

Comment: @Wipqozn I've been here long enough to know better than merely speculate.

Comment: @Fluttershy Source (blizzard developer) added, so the question is no longer off-topic - not being purely speculative.

Comment: @ИвоНедев Irrelevant.  Unless it's playable, it doesn't matter one bit what the developer has said.

Comment: She's released on the PC PTR now, so we can know more for sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

She is mostly invisible except for these cases:

1. If she's right on top of you; if she's right in your face you'll be able to tell that there's an invisible Sombra nearby.
2. If being in the range of a sonic Arrow but **only** through walls
3. Widowmaker's ultimate

[Source](https://www.twitch.tv/unitlost/v/98997531) Tim a Blizzard developer, go to 00:33:35.

Comment: If she's visible in range of Sonic Arrow, I would imagine she's also visible with WM ult, which is basically an infinite range Sonic Arrow.

Comment: Do you have a source for this, or is it a guess?

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft its not a guess, it was stated on live stream by a developer

Comment: So then... you have a source?

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft how's that for a source ?Good enough to reopen, given some of the comments on the question.

Comment: A "sonic" arrow uses, you guessed it, sound to bounce off of physical objects to find people. Widow's technology likely uses something different. Plus, according to the cinematic, Widow had her visor on the entire time. Wouldn't she have seen Sombra and the target standing/talking together for such a length, unless Sombra was somehow immune to Widow's ability?

Comment: @ZealousHypocrites But Infra-Sight does reveal an invisible Sombra. It's quite obvious, you get a big "REVEALED" warning on your screen.

Comment: @Danmaku How do you know? Is there some sort of gameplay video of her? I've only seen the cinematic, and on any other character I've never seen a "Revealed" so I have to assume it's a Sombra gameplay only thing.

Comment: @ZealousHypocrites Check out my Source for 2 hours of gameplay ...

Comment: @ZealousHypocrites You can't base off a cinematic, it's done for entertainment purposes. And widowmaker ult reveals all enemy targets. Sombra is Widow's ally (as far as she knows)

Comment: @Karlyr from yesterday PTR gameplay, you get a big "REVEALED" written above your corsshair when you are in stealth and Widowmaker uses her ult. Same goes for sonic arrow. Also stealth begins to show a visible effect at closer than 5 meters as far as I could tell. Your still stealthed but with a distorted outline and some very minor flickering.

Comment: This doesn't look right. Sonic Arrow should always work, and Deadeye also doesn't show Sombra if she becomes invisible after the ult has started.

Answer (score 4):

**Sombra can be seen by :**

- [Hanzo's Sonic Arrow](http://overwatch.gamepedia.com/Sombra#Thermoptic_Camo) (at all times) (You will be warned by a "Revealed" message)
- [Widowmaker's Infra-Sight](http://overwatch.gamepedia.com/Sombra#Thermoptic_Camo) (You will be warned by a "Revealed" message)
- Being too close to her foes

**She will **not** be revealed by :**

- An enemy Sombra's Opportunist (Her passive revealing foes with less than 50% HP) (Experienced it in 1v1 in the arcade)

**Special Mentions :**

- [A friendly Zarya sheilding an invisible Sombra](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jMGeG7NK9Xo&feature=youtu.be&t=2m24s) will have the shield showing up, but Sombra herself will be invisible rendering only the bubble. (And, by association, revealing Sombra's location)
- [Zenyatta will lose sight of his discord orb](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HG-LPbXCI0I&feature=youtu.be&t=1m41s) if it was attached to a Sombra that turned invisible. (The orb is still attached on the other end)
- [McCree completly lose both his charge and his indicator.](https://youtu.be/1joQTQFgIE0?t=44s)

Comment: I will add source for the opportunist passive and both Widowmaker and Hanzo tonight.